# Как достать данные из Core Data в PickerView? iOS

Tags: ios, coredata

Есть приложение, которое имеет список сотрудников и список поручений. И когда создаешь поручение, в поле TextField должна появляться PickerView со списком сотрудников(с именем). 
Я реализую это так:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Employees"];
        self.empl=[[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
        UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc]init];
        picker.dataSource = self;
        picker.delegate = self;
        [picker setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];
        [self.empTaskField setInputView:picker];
}



 #pragma mark - UIPickerView DataSource Method
    - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{

    return 1;

}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{

        return self->_empl.count;

    }

    #pragma mark - UIPickerView Delegate Method

    -(NSString *) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
        return [_empl objectAtIndex:row];
    }
```

При нажатии на TextField появляется ошибка:

> 2016-03-27 23:32:57.177 Employee Task[2730:150090] -[Employees
>   copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcf2ac84fd0
>   2016-03-27 23:32:57.513 Employee Task[2730:150090] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[Employees copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x7fcf2ac84fd0'

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Приветствую. Покажите пожалуйста полный код контроллера (где объект Employees, его getter)

Comment: `NSManagedObject` и, соответственно, классы от него наследованные, не поддерживают протокол `NSCopying`. то есть при попытке сделать `mutableCopy` вы натыкаетесь на метод которого нет у вашего Employee.